# flyway vers 1.4.2 runs on Java 1.7?

Tags: java, flyway

we are using flyway-core version 1.4.2 and flyway-maven-plugin version 1.4.2 and we need to upgrade our version of Java on our systems to 1.7

I've searched stackoverflow and flywaydb.org (and google of course) for system requirements to see if this version of flyway is supported on Java 1.7 and am not having luck.

i don't have resources to upgrade to the latest version of flyway right now, and we need to move to Java 1.7

does anyone know if this is supported, or will i need to bite the bullet and upgrade flyway to the latest and greatest?

thank you for taking the time to read my request!
scott

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine to upgrade to Java 7 with Flyway 1.4.2. One of Java's strengths is that generally backwards-compatibility is seamless.

Go on and try it! Let us know the result!

Comment: We did as suggested -- ran the Flyway 1.4.2 on Jenkins :-) using Java 1.7 with absolutely NO problems! I thought that Java would be friendly this way, it is nice to confirm it though. Thanks for your response!